# place markers on a map mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox

What's the best why to fill "myStringArray" from a database? the backend is written in ruby, but I only need the javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoiam9zZWYiLCJhIjoib0txbTZwayJ9._0pgdWasmRTVGHE6jY5bvg';
 var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'josef.japp8062')
.setView([59.3329, 18.0513], 5);

var markers = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
function test(){
if(markers){
            markers.clearLayers();
        }     
var myStringArray = [{lon:59.3329, lat: 18.0513},{lon:59.3329, lat: 18.113}];
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  var lon = myStringArray[i].lon;
  var lat = myStringArray[i].lat;
  var latlng = L.latLng(lon,lat);
  var marker = L.marker(latlng, {
      icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
        'marker-color': '#ffffff',
        'marker-size': 'large'
      })
    })
  .bindPopup('coffe <br><img src="../josef.jpg" alt="josef" width="96" height="48" />')
    .addTo(markers);
}
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no general answer for this. Your backend will present an API, and you'll pull from that API here. Ideally your backend produces [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/), and you can simply use a `L.mapbox.featureLayer` to consume it with the `.loadURL` function.

If your backend produces something different, you'll have to do something different, but since we don't know what it produces, we can't tell you what.